# Decent intranet portal software?

Tags: untagged

I am looking for some decent intranet portal software for my 50+ person company. It should provide at least the following functionality: company news, employee directory, photo albums, and hosting of documents.

Does anyone know of anything, open source or commercial?

Answer (score 4):

The only portal software I've used is Liferay ( www.liferay.com/ ). It has all the features you want and more, so it may be overkill for what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Sharepoint Services, Sharepoint Foundation 2010, or Sharepoint Server come to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of PHP-based solutions: [Joomla](http://joomla.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org)

Python/Zope based solution: [Plone](http://plone.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Claromentis is great but might be way too large for your needs.. also it is commercial although it has an open source API

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge Tree (os), TWiki (and all the other os wiki's), Google Sites?, Confluence ($), Alfresco (os & $). SharePoint is probably a safe choice if you use Windows on your servers and desktops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try OpenAtrium (www.openatrium.com). It is a Drupal distribution for dealing with intranets.

Its default settings are really beautiful, but you will have to fiddle a bit in order to have photo albums (but document sharing is available default)

Answer (score 0):

Precurio (as at version 2) had a community edition that was quite okay. Even though it is commercial now, you can still download the version 2 from SourceForge.